# Ssd missing operating system

Tags: boot, ssd, bios

I have ubuntu installed in my ssd and I use it in an old notebook, but I have a better one so I tried to boot the ssd in the newer one but its giving me the Missing Operating System message. I have it working fine in my other notebook so idk what to do. I have the asus vivobook x510u. Its probably some configuration in the bios but I'm new to this stuff and I haven't found something similar to it online. Thanks you in advance

Comment: The new one probably have UEFI and the old one regular BIOS. If Ubuntu is installed in BIOS mode, it won't boot with UEFI. ...just a guess, but given the lack of info, it is the best I can do.

Comment: Yeah it does have UEFI, so in that case I wouldn't be able to use it?

Comment: Well, not the way you've tried to use if. Install Ubuntu in UEFI mode, and it should work on the new machine, but not on the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Download freeware Clonezilla ( https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php ) and make a bootable CD or USB stick with it.  Clone your old drive to some other connected drive.  (Clonezilla can mount USB drives).  Restore the clone to the new drive.  If the new drive is larger, use a bootable drive with gparted on it to resize the partition afterward.

Clonezilla comes from Taiwan, complete with rather lumpy English, but the prompts are correct and the product works.